# Valid iptables Firewall on DD-WRT to access Internet on a Virtual Access Point

Tags: iptables, dd-wrt, vlan, access-point

Device:

```
Linksys WRT54G v5.1
```

Firmware:

```
DD-WRT v24-sp2 (07/22/09) micro - build 12548M NEWD Eko
```

I use this router as an AP with 2 SSIDs (Private wl0 + Guest wl0.1) and I connect it to a switch (Connected to Internet) using the tagged port (port 1).

Both wl0 and wl0.1 can get auto IP in their valid ranges (wl0 : 192.168.1.0/24, wl0.1 : 192.168.2.0/24), **wl0 can access internet but wl0.1 cannot!**

Configuration:

LAN:

```
IP: 192.168.1.3/255.255.255.0
```

Wireless:

```
wl0 : AP bridged
wl0.1 : Virtual AP bridged
```

VLANs:

```
vlan1ports=3t 2 1 0 5*
vlan2ports=3t 5
vlan3ports=4 5
```

Tagging:

```
port0vlans=3 18 19
port1vlans=1 2 16 18 19
port2vlans=1 18 19
port3vlans=1 18 19
port4vlans=1 18 19
port5vlans=1 2 3 16
```

Bridges:

```
br0 : vlan1 eth1 vlan3
br1 (192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0) : wl0.1 vlan2
```

Additional DNSMasq Options:

```
interface=br1
dhcp-range=br1,192.168.2.100,192.168.2.150,255.255.255.0,24h
dhcp-option=br1,3,192.168.2.1
```

**I used this firewall to no avail:**

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -j SNAT --to `nvram get lan_ipaddr`
```

**EDIT:** Setup -> Advanced Routing -> Operating Mode : Router